# Question about congruence modulo n

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences, integers

Is there any sort of algorithm to calculate the remainder when $10^{515}$ is divided by $7$?

Could the same algorithm be applied to finding the remainder of $8^{391}$ divided by $5$?

Is it even necessary to use congruence here?

Comment: Congruences are essentially the same as remainders after division. If you are searching for remainders, you are using congruences. In fact the arithmetic of congruences simplifies the computation of remainders. Here you should look for Fermat's Little Theorem and see if you can solve the problem yourself. Or just investigate the pattern of remainders for small powers (which is a longer method of doing essentially the same thing).

Comment: Definitely a duplicate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) you know that
$$10^6\equiv 1 \mod 7$$
because $7$ is not a divisor of $10$. Now, since
$$10^{515}=10^{6\cdot 85+5}=(10^6)^{85}\cdot 10^5,$$
you get
$$
10^{515}\equiv
(10^6)^{85}\cdot 10^5\equiv
1^{85}\cdot 10^5\equiv
10^5\pmod 7.
$$
Finally, dividing $10^5=100000$ by $7$ the quotient is $14285$ and the remainder is $5$, so $5$ is the solution.

Same thing for $8^{391}\mod 5$: this time $8^4\equiv 1\mod 5$ because $5$ is not a divisor of $8$, then $8^{391}=8^{4\cdot 97+3}$ and so on.

Comment: Once it's down to $10^5$, another approach is $10^5 \equiv 10^{-1} \equiv 3^{-1} \equiv 5 \pmod 7$.

Comment: @Théophile: Can you explain that process to me or link me to a webpage that explains it? I understand almost none of it.

Comment: @aidandeno Have a look at the Wikipedia article on [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) as well as the article on Fermat's Little Theorem that MattAllegro linked to. If you're wondering how I got $10^5 \equiv 10^{-1} \pmod7$, it's because this follows from the first line of MattAllegro's answer:
$$10^6 \equiv 1 \pmod 7\\
10^610^{-1} \equiv 10^{-1} \pmod 7\\
10^5 \equiv 10^{-1} \pmod7$$

Comment: @aidandeno Also, I knew that $3^{-1} \equiv 5 \pmod 7$ because $3\cdot5 = 15 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$.

Answer (score 0):

$10^3\equiv-1\pmod7$

Now $515=(2n+1)3+2$ where $2n+1=171$

$\implies10^{(2n+1)3+2}=(10^3)^{2n+1}\cdot10^2\equiv(-1)^{2n+1}\cdot2\equiv5$

---

$8^2\equiv-1\pmod5$  and $391=4\cdot197+3$

$\implies8^{2(2n+1)+1}=8(8^2)^{2n+1}\equiv3(-1)^{2n+1}\pmod5\equiv2$